# Update PyCharm with new DataGrip

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, datagrip

JetBrains has just released [new DataGrip 2017.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/)

I have Professional edition of PyCharm. This includes working with databases (as I understood all the features of DataGrip).

Is it possible to update my Pycharm, so that it also includes new DataGrip?
I see only minor update possible for now.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need PyCharm 2017.3 which was [released](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/11/pycharm-2017-3-is-out-now/) the 29th of November. I don't know why it doesn't show in the Updates dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded new PyCharm from the link and replaced the old one. Eventually, got my new DataGrip:)